# Is $f(x)\mapsto f(T)$ a ring homomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reviewing linear algebra these days.

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$ over field $F$.

Define $\phi_T(f(X))=f(T)$ for every $f(X)\in F[X]$.

In my text, it's just written there that $f(T)g(T)=g(T)f(T)$, but I thought $\phi_T:F[X]\rightarrow End(V)$ is indeed a ring homomorphism, and I have proven it.

Even though the proof is very direct and easy, I want to make it sure whether it is true.

Is $\phi_T$ a ring homomorphism?

Comment: It is. It feels a little awkward since $F[X]$ is commutative and $\operatorname{End}(V)$ is very much not, but you're only asking that $T$ commute with scalars and itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Considering $F$ as a subring of $\text{End}(V)$ as scalar multiples of $I$, $\phi_T$ is just the "evaluation at $T$" map, which is a homomorphism because $T$ commutes with every element of $F$. This is just an application of the universal property of polynomial rings.